# Telegram Bot Api Webhook does not work

Tags: api, bots, telegram-bot

I've been installing webhook, but it does not work. I have a self-signed-certificate that i've generated from my private key using :

```html
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
```

from this [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed)

But it does not work. It does not even touch my server when i access my access.log. any idea? I'm stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

I try to reply partially as I cannot comment questions yet and you provided not so much information.

From [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) documentation I see that's it's required

> **Notes**
>
> 1. You will not be able to receive updates using [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) for as long as an outgoing webhook is set up.
> 2. To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your [public key certificate](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed) using *certificate* parameter. Please upload as
>    InputFile, sending a String will not work.
> 3. Ports currently supported for Webhooks: **443, 80, 88, 8443**.

[More info](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed).

So in you case I think you should provide the file of your pub key while setting the webhook. In `curl` that should looks like the following.

```
curl https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook \
    -F "url=yoururl" \
    -F "certificate=@pathToPubKey"
```

Check out the [setWebhook API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).